# How to change or view the input stream when writing bison in C++?

Tags: c++, gnu, bison

How do I know how it knows what the input stream is? Can I use the specified file as the yylex inputstream? It is really confusing to write bison in C++

Bison source code

```
%require "3.2"
%language "c++"

%start program

%nterm <std::string> program s

%token <std::string> TEXT "hello world";


%define api.value.type variant
%define api.token.constructor
%code
{
    namespace yy
    {
        // Return the next token.
        auto yylex() -> parser::symbol_type
        {
            static int count = 0;
            switch (int stage = count++)
            {
                case 0:
                    return parser::make_TEXT("sss11");
                case 1:
                    return parser::make_TEXT("hello world");
                default:
                    return parser::make_YYEOF();
            }
        }
    }
}


%%

program :
    s s  { std::cout << $1 << std::endl; }
;

s :
    %empty  { /* ignore */ }
|   TEXT    { $$ = $1; std::cout << "text $1" << std::endl; }
;

%%

namespace yy {
    auto parser::error(const std::string& msg) -> void
    {
        std::cerr << msg << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    yy::parser parse;
    return parse();
}
```

Program output

```
text $1
text $1
sss11
```

I used the C language to write flexbison before, and later discovered that llvm needs the AST structure provided by bison written in c++, and then I had to learn from the documentation to write bison in C++, but now it makes me very distressed...
After looking for a day in the official documentation, I still can’t find where it got the input stream from and then yylex parsing and then parsing parse.

Big guys come and take a look and ask for a solution. Thank you

Comment: "and later discovered that llvm needs the AST structure provided by bison written in c++" What do you mean by that? LLVM doesn't care what your AST looks like or how you've generated it - or whether you even have one.

Comment: I'm also not sure I understand your question about input streams. Bison doesn't read from any streams - it gets its tokens by calling `yylex` and it's up to `yylex` where it gets its input from. Usually `yylex` will read characters from a file or stdin and turn those into tokens, but In the code you posted it just returns a hard-coded sequence of tokens and doesn't read anything. So there are no streams involved. Note that, other than `yylex` living inside a namespace, none of this is really specific to C++.

Comment: @sepp2k Then how do I write the input stream, specify to let yylex input the data of a file, and then convert it into a token and give it to bison for grammatical analysis

Comment: @user15390060: you can just use flex to build a lexical scanner; nothing needs to be changed. Flex generates scanner code which will compile in both C and C++, and it also has a specific C++ template if you want to use that.

Comment: @rici Okay, can you give me a link to a C++ template example? I can't seem to find it.
I used flex to write the scanner before, and then bison to write grammatical analysis, but because only C language statements can be used to write the code or semantic actions of the C language part, I searched for such code and studied it, but in the document It doesn't seem to be given how to use flex and bison that write semantic actions in c++ together.

Comment: @user15390060: you can use c++ in flex actions, because the generated scanner works with either C or C++. If you know how to use flex in C, that's probably the easiest. There is a complete example in the bison manual in the C++ section, and the soutce code is part of the bison distribution.

Comment: Here's a link to the documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#A-Complete-C_002b_002b-Example